# custom field - changing an element or background of id div - different versions not working

Tags: php, customization, css, javascript

I want to change the background-proberty value of an element (div id = Box2) 
what sits in a container div with red background.

Box2 should has a background attribute of the specified post-metakey/custom field value.

When I insert the normal php set of the customfield to show off to the footer.php it shows all the different used values of the specied article.

The stylesheet is a style.css.php file. I tried 4 Versions and all do not work.

The custom field is: custombg($key) yellow (value)

What do i do wrong? none of these versions are working.

Here is the Code:

V1 - (style1.css.php) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');
  $newBG = "darkviolet";
?>

#Box2 {
background: <?php echo $newBG ?> ;
}

#Box2 {
background:red
}
```

V2 - (style2.css.php) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');
  $newBG = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custombg', true);
?>


#Box2 {
background: <?php echo $newBG ?> ;
}

#Box2 {
background:red
}
```

V3 - (style3.css.php) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

#Box2 {
background: <?php the_field('custombg') ?> ;
}

#Box2 {
background:red
}
```

V4 - (style4.css.php) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

#Box2 {
background: <?php echo the_field('custombg') ?> ;
}

#Box2 {
background:red
}
```

/* --WP Check (all works fine)- - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

```
<?php the_meta();?> /* gives out every post-meta-key + values */
<br><br>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custombg', true); ?> /* gives out specified post-meta-key + values */
<br><br>
<?php the_field('custombg'); ?> /* gives out specified post-meta-key value */
```

/* --PHP/HTML values to inject- - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

```
<div id="Box1" style="background:red">
<div id="Box2">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't use WordPress functions in a standalone php file, there is no WordPress environment loaded in that context.

Comment: Is there another solution what you might suggest? I am also trying it with js at the moment but there i also have the problem that i need informations from outside the loop. There must be a way... I thought when i link it in the header its inside the loop but i guess its not right? Is there a way that i can load my style.css.php file into the loop?

Answer (score 0):

In most themes anything added via the `wp_head` hook should appear after (and override) enqueued CSS.

So you could add an action to the themes functions.php and use `get_queried_object_id()` for the post ID.

```
function my_dynamic_css() {
  $custombg = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'custombg', true );
  if (! empty($custombg)) {
   ?><style>#Box2 {background: <?php echo $custombg; ?> }</style>
  <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_dynamic_css');
```

Presumably, rather than having the rest of your CSS in a PHP file you could enqueue it as a standard CSS file. If not you could "include" it by adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/pathto/my/style1.css" />` to the above function or use [heredoc](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/3/heredoc).